# How to include code samples in a WPF/Silverlight Component example application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting

I am working on the example application for a WPF & Silverlight component. As is common with these sorts of example applications, I would like to show C#/Xaml code to the end-user to assist them with creating their own applications with this component.

As a visual example of what I am trying to acheive, see here: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/silverlight/ 
This is the Bing Maps SDK example application. Notice how each example there is a tab with "Show Me" - the example, and "Source Code". A screenshot is also included below:

[image]

The examples application needs to both compile the source and display the source for both WPF and Silverlight. I don't want to include the source twice, as if the source for an example updates, I want to recompile and the "Source Code" tab should display the updated code.

Consider a typical example may consist of 1..N files in a folder, e.g.

- AllExamples/SomeExample

  - SomeExampleView.xaml
  - SomeExampleView.xaml.cs
  - SomeExampleViewModel
  - SomeExampleConverter

How can I configure my project/solution to pick these source files up and not only compile them, but also get the text to display in the examples app "source code" tab, with the minimum fuss and avoiding copy/passting into a separate file?

Any suggestions welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Naive solution. Just add post-build event to your project that copies your sources to output directory and your "source code" tab can just read and show these files.

Comment: Aha,of course. Simple answers are always the best. Now I forgot yo mention I am targetting both Silverlight and wpf. Could I include the source in xap file using a similar method?